# Unable to run Trusted Web Activity after upgrading to Android 12 (SDK 31)

Tags: trusted-web-activity, android-12

Recently we are preparing for Android 12 and we updated our compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31
After updating to 31, TWA is unable to be launched. Error given is

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: xxx.twa: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
        at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsClient.createSessionId(CustomTabsClient.java:231)
        at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsClient.newSession(CustomTabsClient.java:269)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher$TwaCustomTabsServiceConnection.onCustomTabsServiceConnected(TwaLauncher.java:324)
        at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(CustomTabsServiceConnection.java:57)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:2077)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:2110)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

After updating androidx.browser:browser `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0-beta01'` i got the below error

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: xxx.twa: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.FocusActivity.addToIntent(FocusActivity.java:43)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher.launchWhenSplashScreenReady(TwaLauncher.java:272)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher.lambda$launchWhenSessionEstablished$4$TwaLauncher(TwaLauncher.java:257)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.-$$Lambda$TwaLauncher$6zo6viK_vVSs4bt2THXs48ruews.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.lambda$onSplashImageTransferred$1$PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:208)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.-$$Lambda$PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy$p-f_rUE4TsZEGw17K3MBDrUxlsQ.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.runWhenEnterAnimationComplete(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:215)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.onSplashImageTransferred(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:207)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.lambda$configureTwaBuilder$0$PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:195)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.-$$Lambda$PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy$AEuRt7oVnGOP2vf-Uvl2RaqkFW4.onFinished(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.SplashImageTransferTask$1.onPostExecute(SplashImageTransferTask.java:144)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.SplashImageTransferTask$1.onPostExecute(SplashImageTransferTask.java:91)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I tried to find an updated version of com.google.androidbrowserhelper but is unable to find any. I am currently using `implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper:2.2.2'`

Have anyone encounter this and is able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and needs changes on the underlying `androidx.browser` library. The changes are in [`1.4.0-rc1`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser#1.4.0-rc01), which should go stable in the next weeks. Another [change](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/pull/338) was required in `android-browser-helper` and once the change to `androidx.browser` is out, we'll release an update that will work well with targetSdk 31.

You could use the release-candidate version of android.browser and build your own android-browser-helper, but I'd recommend waiting for the production versions to upgrade to target SDK 31.

Comment: Thanks. i will keep a lookout for update to production version